# Testing formatting of dates before save in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-directive

I am using the angular-ui bootstrap datepicker across an application and it works very well.  However the backend I am sending the dates to only accepts dates in a given format, sadly this format is not what is the default that is put on the model for the date picker.

To combat this issue I have a few `if` checks that I run through before I persist the model.  This does not scale very well on forms that have multiple dates.

```
if ($scope.dateOfBirthStr) {
  $scope.dateOfBirthStr = $filter('date')($scope.dateOfBirthStr, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
}
```

Without modifying the ui-datepicker itself is there an best practice I can use to format all the dates within a given model without having to call them out individually?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly: You have problems converting the javascript Date used by the datepicker to a format your backend understands ?

What is the format your backend is accepting and how to you connect Angular to that backend?
I personally use the the angular-ui datepicker with normal javascript Date objects ($scope.myDate = new Date() ... )
You should convert the dates only within the function that connects your angular-app to the backend.

(As I have node as a backend I never had that problem)

Comment: the backend only accepts a string in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. Which is why I am using a filter to change the dates to that format before persisting it.  I am just trying to look for an easier way to do this instead of hard coding every date field on a model to be formatted.